# In a general group, is $axb=cxd$ possible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$a$, $ b $, $ c $, and $d$ are in a group $G$,

Is there any example that $axb=cxd$, but $ab \ne cd$?

Answer (score 3):

So $x (bd^{-1}) = (a^{-1} c) x$ but $bd^{-1} \ne a^{-1} c$.
There are examples in any non-abelian group: if $x y \ne y x$,
take $b d^{-1} = y$ and $a^{-1} c = x y x^{-1}$.

Comment: Aren't the $a,b,c,d$ fixed in this question though?

Comment: @SteveD: It's not clear to me that they are fixed.  If $a,b,c,d$ are fixed, then it may or may not be true that $axb = cxd$.  This would say
$a^{-1} c$ and $b d^{-1}$ are related by an inner automorphism $y \to x y x^{-1}$.

Comment: Ok, I was taking it as "solve this equation for x".

Answer (score 1):

For example if you take $G=S_3$, then by examining the elements which is: $$\{(), (2,3), (1,2), (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (1,3)\}$$ you see that $$(2,3)*(1,2,3)*(1,3,2)=(1,3,2)*(1,2,3)*(2,3)$$ but $$(2,3),~~~(1,3,2)$$ are not commutable.

Comment: Nice (counter)example! +1